# PHP Kohana routing not work

Tags: php, kohana

I have bootstrap.php:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/wypoczynek/',
    'index_file' => false,
));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('dodaj-obiekt', 'dodaj-obiekt(/<action>(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'object',
        'action'     => 'addObject',
    ));
```

And .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /wypoczynek/

<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Link: http://domain.pl/wypoczynek works good, but http://domain.pl/wypoczynek/dodaj-obiekt not works. I see 404 error page, default 404 error page by Apache. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

More generic routes should go last. They match in the order they match in declaration, so put your default route last.